# Perl /e regexp adding unexpected character

Tags: perl

I have a one-line Perl script (Perl v5.10.1) that is behaving in a way that I cannot understand or explain:

```
$ cat packer-build.log |
>   perl -MPOSIX -pe \
>     's/^(\d+)/my $x = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", localtime($1)); print "$x "/e' | tail -5
2017-06-21 11:11 1,,error-count,1
2017-06-21 11:11 1,,ui,error,\n==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
2017-06-21 11:11 1,amazon-ebs,error,unexpected EOF
2017-06-21 11:11 1,,ui,error,--> amazon-ebs: unexpected EOF
2017-06-21 11:11 1,,ui,say,\n==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

Unfiltered output:

```
$ tail -5 packer-build.log 
1498007467,,error-count,1
1498007467,,ui,error,\n==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
1498007467,amazon-ebs,error,unexpected EOF
1498007467,,ui,error,--> amazon-ebs: unexpected EOF
1498007467,,ui,say,\n==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

Notice that there is a `1` after `2017-06-21 11:11` which is not present in the unfiltered output.

What is causing this to be printed and how can I modify the code so that I get the epoch time in field 1 to be replaced with human readable output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `/e` in a substitution, the match will be replaced with whatever the substitution code evaluates to. You have a call to `print()` in your code and `print()` returns a true value (1) when a print is successful. That's what you're seeing in your replacement.

But you don't need that `print()`. Replace your code with this:

```
s/^(\d+)/my $x = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", localtime($1)); $x/e
```

Or, even simpler:

```
s/^(\d+)/strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", localtime($1))/e
```

Comment: There was a space added in the print, add that to the format string if desired

Comment: Actually, that space was only intended to make it clearer that the "1" was not part of the time string.